# How do I show the hard drive on the desktop

Tags: desktop

My hard drive used to display on the desktop. It's gone missing, how do I get it back?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go into Finder, then go to the menu bar and click Finder -> Preferences. Select the "General" tab and check "Hard disks" under "Show these items on the desktop":

[image]